# Estimate an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I'm wondering if there exists a constant $C$ such that we can have the following estimation for the integral for $\alpha >1$ and $t> 0$:

$$\int_{t}^{\infty} \left(1+x^2\right)^{-\alpha} \ dx \leq Ct^{-2\alpha}$$

Comment: Nope, that's too much to ask for in the exponent. Try it with $\alpha = 1$, for example.

Comment: Is the C supposed to be uniform in both $t$ and $\alpha$? Also, for $\alpha=1$ you have a $\Theta(t^{-1})$ type decay for large t.

Comment: @user296602 I think it should be $\alpha >1$, and I have modified the condition.

Comment: @Curran ok... try it with $\alpha = 2.$

Comment: **Usually**, relations with $\approx$ are called *approximations*, and relations with $\lt$, $\gt$, $\le$ or $\ge$ are called *inequalities*. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Generally you get a rigorous *approximation* by giving a combination of lower and upper bounds of similar character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha > 1/2,$ the expression goes like $$ \int_t^\infty x^{-2\alpha}\;dx \propto t^{-2\alpha +1}$$ which decays slower than $t^{-2\alpha},$ so no.